# Swift - Audio is not playing when button is pressed. Why?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

Here's my code:

```
let laFlame = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "laflame", ofType: "mp3")!)
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func laFlame(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: laFlame)
        audioPlayer.play()

    } catch {
        // Could not load file.
    }
}
```

I get no errors, but whenever the button is pressed, nothing happens and the sound doesn't play. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this method instead of `AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:)`.

```
@IBAction func laFlame(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: laFlame, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!